# dynamically resize the actual image in android how can implemented

Tags: android, resize-image

i am worked on android application in this application image saved in byte code,in this byte code convert image

in this original image resize in smaller image and clarity image  dynamically how can implemented in android

please forward some valuable solution thanks in advance...

Comment: please give us a little more detail. What have you already tried ? What exactly are you trying to achieve ? What do you mean by " image saved in byte code,in this byte code convert image" ?

Comment: retrieve image done , in this image big size how we can resize the original image  i am add that image in list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert Image to Bitmap and use scaled bitmap method of bitmap to specifying size of your scaled down/up image, use ImageView.setBitmap method to set this image bitmap to your Ui element.